# String conversion to look like python list

Tags: bash

I have a string like
'string1,string2,string3'

I want to convert the same to
["string1","string2","string3"]

I tried using

```
sed 's/\(,\)/"\1"/g'
```

But its returning `string1","string2","string3`

Comment: You should be aware that the proposed solutions will produce syntactically incorrect ouputs when the input contains double quotes. Depending on your use case, this probably doesn't matter, but if your strings might contain american measurements with inches abbreviated as " this can lead to unpleasant surprises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already can insert quotes around the commas, just tack on `["` and `"]` at the start and end:

```
sed 's/^/["/; s/\(,\)/"\1"/g; s/$/"]/'
```

Example:

```
$ echo string1,string2,string3 | sed 's/^/["/; s/\(,\)/"\1"/g; s/$/"]/'
["string1","string2","string3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure bash solution:

```
$ str='string1,string2,string3'
$ echo "[\"${str//,/\",\"}\"]"
["string1","string2","string3"]
```

Because this approach requires no external utilities and no subprocesses, this should be fast.

#### How it works

We use bash's *pattern substitution* to replace all commas with `","`.  Because `"` is a shell-active character, we must escape it in the command:

```
$ echo ${str//,/\",\"}
string1","string2","string3
```

The last step is to add on `["` to the beginnign and `"]` to the end of the string.  Thus:

```
$ echo "[\"${str//,/\",\"}\"]"
["string1","string2","string3"]
```